Can you use adaptive cards as content when using the calendar module in teamsjs?
Currently using the calendar module from teamjs to directly schedule appointments in the users outlooks/teams calendar.
import { calendar } from '@microsoft/teams-js'

calendar.composeMeeting({
        subject: 'I am subject',
        content: `<p>I am content</p>`
    })

Is it possible to add an adaptive card here as content?
Specifically we want to add an adaptive card that will open a dialog where we provide it a url for playing videos.
What we are doing right now is just deeplinking directly to our app from the appointment but this doesn't really work for outlook as the deeplink will open in msteams.
